# database connection pool purpose?

Tags: java, sql, database, connection-pooling

Considering a simple thread pool. The main purpose of a thread pool is reusing(recycling) a thread in order to limit the maximum number of threads and preventing of remove and create threads, am I right?
Recently I have read(wikipedia connection pool) that in Java EE, database connection are pooled by server, but I cannot figure out why?
**Questions:**

- What is the main purpose of pooling sql connection in java?
- Is it okay to pool 128 connections and keep all of them open?
- What is the difference if 128 concurrent select commands get run by one connection or 128 connection?
- What is the correct way to connect to the database through a connection pool?
- How do both server and database handle the connections?
- How does server reuse a closed connection?
- Is pool still necessary when whole server components use a shared connection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Database connections are pooled by the database *client.* A J2EE server is a client of the database.

Comment: @EJP Good point, I also found connection pool configuration within `MS SQL Server` too, so is it related to the server? or the management studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Database connection pooling solve is very similar to the thread pooling you have mentioned here. Here are the main reasons.

- Main purpose of the db connection pool is to create some db
  connections and keep them in the pool and reuse them whenever your
  application code need to execute queries to db. Because creation of
  connections is a very costly operation, Connection pooling allows us
  to save that effort.
- It is perfectly fine to create 128 connections and keep them in the pool.
- No 128 concurrent selects on one connection may not work properly. With connection pooling you get the connection from the
  pool and the use it to fire all the queries that are required for the
  operation and then you return the connection back to the pool. So you
  would need 128 connections to run the concurrent selects.
- Generally you let the container handle the connection pooling. You can configure connection pooling in web.xml or in the container
  specify configuration file and associate a JNDI name with data source
  that is connected to the pool. Then you lookup that DataSource and
  get the connections from there. Here is the example code for getting
  connections.

> ```
> public static Connection getConnection() {
>         Connection con = null;
>         try {
>             Context initContext = new InitialContext();
>             Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
>             DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/db");
>             con = dataSource.getConnection();
>         } catch (NamingException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } catch (SQLException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>         return con;
>     }
> ```

- Database will assume that the connection are still alive and its the
  responsibility of the application server to keep the connections in
  the pool alive (of course by the configuration by user) and avoid the
  connection timeouts.
- When your application code requests the connection to be closed by calling connection.close(), This connection is not closed and is actually returned to the pool so that further requests for connections from the pool will use this connection.
- For all web applications its is strongly advised that you create the connection pool else you will run into problems related to
  performance and too many connections opened.

Comment: So you mean I have to get a new connection from connection pool for each Servlet request, and then close it(request scope)?

Comment: Yes but as mentioned in the answer above when you close the connection it just goes back to the pool rather than actually closing the connection.

Comment: "It is perfectly fine to create 128 connections and keep them in the pool.". There's nothing perfectly fine about it. The database most likely can't handle 128 simultaneous operations, so it can end up exhausting the DB server's resources. This will then make all the 128 connections hang, and your system will be unusable to users.